# Make folders opened by external apps open in a new finder tab rather than a window

Tags: finder, macos, tabs, launchbar

I have the setting "open folders in new tabs" (instead of new windows) in finder turned on but this does not seem to influence what my other apps do when *they* open a folder. Launchbar and a shell script I run from emacs still opens folders in small finder windows. How can I make folders opened from external apps all appear in one tabbed finder window?

Edit: Bmike in the comment is right that this could probably be done via an applescript. Something like this:

1. You have some script that gives you the path of the folder you want to open.
2. You pass this as a variable to an applescript.
3. This applescript saves the pathname as a variable
4. It activates finder or opens a particular folder with finder.
5. It sends the keystroke command + t to open a new tab (or does the same with a command to finder).
6. It sends the keystroke command + shift + g to finder opening the go to folder with path x menu/window.
7. It writes (systemevents) or pastes it (set clipboard to the variable that is the path of the folder) into this menu/window.
8. Click enter. The folder is opened.

Comment: I want the same.

Comment: I have the same problem, question on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/688439/open-new-finder-tab-when-using-open-in-the-terminal

Comment: It seems like this is is under the application's settings, not just Finder's.

Comment: Can you share the shell script or launchbar details? It might be possible to embed an AppleScript call in them to tell finder to open a new tab.

Comment: launchbar just opens stuff automatically, in shell scripts I use the open command https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html, to open via emacs in dired I use this script http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/make-folders-opened-by-external-apps-open-in-a-new-finder-tab-rather-than-a-wind?noredirect=1#comment144612_106131

Comment: I guess you're right that as long as you have the path you can open via an applescript, you need the folder path as a variable and could then do activate finder, cmd t, cmnd shift g, then paste/write the folder path in the go to folder command that appears, then then send return

Answer (score 1):

I did this, not sure if it will answer it for you.

Finder Preferences > General > check "open folders in tabs instead of new windows"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the idea. I got the applescript finished.

Put the following in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`

```
# open the current folder in Finder's tab
function oft() {
    # if no arguments are given, we use the current folder
    oft_absolute_path=$(cd ${1:-.}; pwd)

    # execute the applescirpt
    osascript 2>/dev/null <<EOF

        # Finder returns a path with trailing slash
        # But PWD doesn't have one, so we add one for it
        set new_tab_path to "$oft_absolute_path" & "/"

        tell application "Finder"
            activate

            if not (exists window 1) then
                make new Finder window
            end if

            try
                set finder_path to POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)
            on error
                # the finder's window doesn't contain any folders
                set target of front window to (new_tab_path as POSIX file)
                return
            end try
        end tell

        if new_tab_path = finder_path then
            # the finder's tab is already there
            return
        end if

        # open new tab in Finder
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down

        # set the Finder's path
        tell application "Finder"
            set target of front window to (new_tab_path as POSIX file)
        end tell

        return
    EOF
    # clear the tempory veriable
    unset oft_absolute_path
}
```

In terminal, type

```
oft .
```

to open the current folder in Finder's new tab.

The bash script is used for retrieving the absolute path, which I found difficult to do in appplescript.

***UPDATE***

I have made a more extensive (and complicated) version which will open the same tab for the same folder. [Get it here](https://gist.github.com/haifengkao/072136412953619d51bc8d21e28e61b4)